# Copy the newest file from folder and exclude files by part of the name via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I try to copy the newest file from folder (.exe files) by using this type of command:

```
Get-ChildItem "K:\" -File -include "*.exe" | Where-Object { $_. $_.LastWriteTime like "I don't know which parameter I should type here} Copy-Item -Path $files -Destination "C:\"
```

I don't want to use complex script with variables and etc. (for now)

Here is folder structure which I have:

- Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287638x64_NoDB.exe
- Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287638x64.exe
- Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287337x64_NoDB.exe
- Release_OSInstaller_2015_CL287337x64.exe

And so on. Basically every day a new build is deployed in folder where from I copied the file to my machine (remote).

I need to create a script which will copy the newest build but I want to exclude all files with "NoDB.exe" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the [answer from whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37853139/1163423), you could add a `Where` condition and skip the `NoDB`files:

```
Get-ChildItem "K:\" -Filter '*.exe' | 
    Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | 
    sort LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    select -first 1 | 
    Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\'
```

Comment: Martin, thank you so much! That is what I want! Hurray!

Comment: Unfortunately I messed up in my first answer, it doesn't work (or at least not in PS v3), so since Martin Brandls is based on it, it won't work either. The corrected solution should work. Alternatively this will work, too:
`Get-ChildItem "K:\" -Filter '*.exe' | 
    Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | 
    sort LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    select -ExpandProperty Fullname -first 1 | 
    Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\'`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is the fastest way (probably not). But if you are not crawling through huge filesystems

```
Copy-Item -Path (Get-ChildItem "K:\" -File -include "*.exe" |
Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | Sort-Object -Descending
LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1) -Destination "C:\"
```

should do the trick. (My first answers seems to have been wrong ;) )
And I totally missed the excluding condition so now Martin Brandl Addition is included ^^

Comment: Thank you. But how exclude "NoDB.exe" parameter? Because I need build without "NoDB.exe" parameter in name.